# Can't use the returned Email & Token from AsyncStorage / SecureStore in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, callback, expo, asyncstorage

I've searched around for and answer to my problem, but I can't seem to find anything like it. 
My code is returning a value as expected!

I'm building an app in React-Native and am currently working on the login. I need to save the userId, userEmail, and userToken, and  came up with AsyncStorage and Expo's SecureStore as options, but I've got a really odd problem that I've never seen before.

I can set and read the required data, but when I try and use it, it just doesn't work, but when I hardcode it, it does? (*it's a little hard to explain*).

This is where the problem lies. For ease of reading I have left out the rest of the code, it works just fine if I hardcode the values below...

```
    // Set the email and token
    // Before setting these, I logged the key's values and (of course), they were null
    // After setting them I logged them out again and they're set

/** from promise (no problems) **/

    SecureStore.setItemAsync('shifterEmail', responseJson.email);
    SecureStore.setItemAsync('shifterToken', responseJson.token);

/** returns response (no problems) **/
```

...meanwhile, further down the page...

```
/** another function **/
    let shifterEmail = '';
    let shifterToken = '';

    SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterEmail')
        .then((email) => {
            shifterEmail = email;
            console.log('API email: ', shifterEmail); // my@email.com <- good!
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('API email error: ', error);
        });

    SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterToken')
        .then((token) => {
            shifterToken = token;
            console.log('API token: ', shifterToken); // random token <- good!
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('API token error: ', error);
        });

    return {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token' +
        ' token=' + shifterToken + // WHAAAT <- doesn't work
        ', email=' + shifterEmail, // WHAAAT <- doesn't work
    };
```

I had a brainwave and though it might've been good old asynchronicity, and tried nesting them in their callbacks, but it makes no difference.
I've shown the code for `SecureStore` here, but it's the same with `AsyncStorage`, i can get the expected values for the email and token, but it just doesn't work.

**But, here's the odd bit, that I don't understand...**

if I hardcode the token and email in the return, it works just fine!

*mind = blown*

- I can use `typeof` to ensure its a string.
- I've tried `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` on set and get.
- I've tried setting and getting it in-line, and as callable functions.
- I've tried nesting the callbacks, and leaving them sequential.
- I even tried adding a timeout to the return to make sure everything's been set.

...nothing works :(

*On a side note:* These are both strings, but I had the same problem with a number, and the only way I got it to work was to bring the 'get' (from both AsyncStorage and SecureStore) out of their callable functions and have the code in-line.
Also, if, instead of saving the email and token I just add it to a variable and use that in the return, it works just fine, but this is no good as the user would have to log in every time they open the app.

Totally baffled. Happy to answer any questions, I've tried loads, so we can have a good old chat, or, if you can suggest a different way of handling logging in, I'd love to hear that too!

Why can't I use the value when it's RIGHT THERE, but can hardcode the same thing ???

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's an async issue. Based on the code snippet you have provided the return statement could possibly run before the `.then` callback is called.

An easy fix could be to use `async/await` or `Promise.all`

For example:

**Async/Await**

```
const getToken = async () => {
    try{
      const email = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterEmail')
      const token = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterToken')

      return {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token' +
        ' token=' + token + 
        ', email=' + email
      };
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    }
 }
```

**Promise.all**

```
 const getToken = () => {
    Promise.all([
      SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterEmail'),
      SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterToken')  
    ])
   .then((response) => {
      const [email, token] = response
       return {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Token' +
          ' token=' + token + 
          ', email=' + email
        };
      }
    ).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      throw error;
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still the same. I can log out the email and token, but it doesn't accept them in the return... and they looked so Promising! (bdum tsh... <- get it?! Ha!). On the back of this, I tried wrapping the return block in an IF statement (e.g. `IF(email === 'my@Email.com)`) so that it has to match before proceeding which they do, but it still doesn't accept the email and token :(

Answer (score 0):

The above code is run asynchronously and, as such, the below code in the return statement has not been set yet.

You haven't posted the entire function, but a return statement probably won't work here and you'll need to pass a callback function.

```js
const doSomethingWithLogin = headers =>
  console.log(headers)
  
Promise.all([
  SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterEmail'),
  SecureStore.getItemAsync('shifterToken')  
])
  .then(([shifterEmail, shifterToken]) =>
    Promise.resolve({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token' +
      ' token=' + shifterToken + 
      ', email=' + shifterEmail,
    })
  )
  .then(doSomethingWithLogin)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still the same. I can log the email and token out, but they fail when I use them :(

Answer (score 0):

Really old question, but I just ran into the same issue and think I know the answer.

after getting token from storage, when doing something like:

`'token=' + token`
what actually comes out is:
`token="sadfaswerw"`
In other words, the token is wrapped in quotes for some reason.
Simple enough to replace the quotes, but a bit odd.

Comment: if I remember rightly it was that the promise wasn't being consumed when I was using it, and as such I was returning the promise and not the promise value.

Comment: I went back to this, and realised problem on my side was that I was storing the token as json.